# Can't access new Workbook from inside a function

Tags: excel, vba, scope

I'm trying to access information from other workbooks and populate that information in a central location. Specifically, I'm trying to write a function that can be used in a cell that will return the UsedRange.Count of the target Workbook.

The problem is that I keep getting an Err #9 or #91 when I try to point to the workbook object. I am 99.99% sure I am naming the file correctly.

What's more, when I run the code as a Sub as opposed to a Function it works fine.

Here is the working Sub:

```
Sub test()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Dim fileName As String
    Dim rootDir As String

    Dim BigSum As Integer

    rootDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path
    fileName = "TestSheet1"

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    MsgBox rootDir

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wb2 = Workbooks(fileName & ".xlsx")

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(rootDir & "\Test1\" & fileName & ".xlsx")

    MsgBox wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value2

    BigSum = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Count - 2

    MsgBox BigSum

End Sub
```

Now here's an example of the Function:

```
Function Adder(exTension As String, fileName As String) As Integer

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook

    Dim rootDir As String

    rootDir = ActiveWorkbook.Path

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wb2 = Workbooks(fileName & ".xlsx")

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(rootDir & "\" & exTension & "\" & fileName & ".xlsx")

    Adder = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Count - 2

    MsgBox Adder

errHandler:

    MsgBox Err.Number

    Resume exitHere

exitHere:

End Function
```

As far as I can tell, there's no real difference between these. Is this a issue with scope?

Comment: Functions called as UDF's have a number of restrictions: you can't do what you want using a UDF   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/170787

Comment: Are you sure the sub is working fine? It has an `On Error Resume Next` in it...

Comment: @arcadeprecinct On Error Resume Next was just a quick way to open the file if it wasn't already open.

Comment: @MikhailYatsevitch ok but then you should disable it after that line. You are wondering why one version is giving an error and the other isn't so the first thing would be to use the same error handling in both functions/subs.